# How do i print a fetchone() function but get NoneType error? Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to print the fetchone() value but it just gives me the error `'NoneType' object is not iterable`, does anyone know why

Here is my code:

```
def viewemaillook():
        global realusername
        global realpassword
        viewemail = input("Would you like to see/change your email")
        if viewemail == "y" or viewemail == "yes":
            c.execute("SELECT email, * FROM stuffToPlot WHERE username = ?  and password = ?", (realusername,realpassword,))
            grab = c.fetchone()
            for i in grab:
                print(i)
        elif viewemail == "n" or "no":
            print("Okay")
        else:
            print("Invalid option")
            viewemaillook()
    viewemaillook()
else:
    print("Not a valid option")
    change()
change()
```

Answer (score 1):

If your query is not finding any results, then `fetchone()` will return `None`. When you try to loop over `grab` which is equal to `None` you are getting the error. Try checking if you have a result in `grab` first.

Comment: it is printing ("None") any idea why? I have an email saved for it in the database

Comment: Not sure, is your cursor pointing to the right database? Is the table name correct? Could be a variety of reasons. Try running the query first by hard coding the values.